# Data analysis method for 1 independent variable and several dependent variables?

Tags: r, anova, continuous-data, discrete-data, kruskal-wallis-test

I am working on a fertilizer experiment, involving three different treatments of fertilizer. I wish to evaluate the relationship between the treatments (independent variables) with several different measurements (yield, plant biomass, plant count before treatment, plant count after treatment). The program I am using is RStudio.

The issue that I'm running up against here (despite being new to statistics and ANOVA) is that I wish to look at two continuous variables and two discrete variables. As can be seen by the data below, yield and plant biomass are continuous variables, whereas plant count before and after treatments are discrete.

To evaluate if yield depends on treatment type and if plant biomass depends on treatment type, I ran a Kruskal-Wallis test (because the data is not normally distributed and the dataset has homogeneity of variance). Am I right in saying that I cannot use this same procedure to evaluate Plant count before and after treatment, because they are not continuous? And if so, does anybody have a recommendation as to what would be the best method to evaluate these two parameters? I would think regression would work, but I'm not quite sure as to what kind of regressional analysis would work best.

My dataset can be viewed by creating the following dataframe in R:

```
data <- data.frame(treatment=c(2,
                               2,
                               2,
                               2,
                               2,
                               2,
                               2,
                               2,
                               2,
                               2,
                               2,
                               2,
                               2,
                               2,
                               2,
                               2,
                               2,
                               2,
                               2,
                               3,
                               3,
                               3,
                               3,
                               3,
                               3,
                               3,
                               3,
                               3,
                               3,
                               3,
                               3,
                               3,
                               3,
                               3,
                               3,
                               3,
                               3,
                               3,
                               4,
                               4,
                               4,
                               4,
                               4,
                               4,
                               4,
                               4,
                               4,
                               4,
                               4,
                               4,
                               4,
                               4,
                               4,
                               4,
                               4,
                               4,
                               4),
                   yield = c(4754.51354135,
                             4583.51354135,
                             4183.51354135,
                             4818.51354135,
                             4081.51354135,
                             4177.51354135,
                             4759.51354135,
                             4455.51354135,
                             4703.51354135,
                             4244.51354135,
                             4114.51354135,
                             4871.51354135,
                             4472.51354135,
                             4627.51354135,
                             4555.51354135,
                             4315.51354135,
                             4093.51354135,
                             4203.51354135,
                             4542.51354135,
                             4513.51354135,
                             4858.51354135,
                             4475.51354135,
                             4529.51354135,
                             4378.51354135,
                             4169.51354135,
                             4741.51354135,
                             4213.51354135,
                             4571.51354135,
                             4809.51354135,
                             4694.51354135,
                             4228.51354135,
                             4209.51354135,
                             4972.51354135,
                             4200.51354135,
                             4466.51354135,
                             4464.51354135,
                             4682.51354135,
                             4962.51354135,
                             4784.51354135,
                             4963.51354135,
                             4809.51354135,
                             4899.51354135,
                             4218.51354135,
                             4487.51354135,
                             4722.51354135,
                             4742.51354135,
                             4516.51354135,
                             4452.51354135,
                             4912.51354135,
                             4392.51354135,
                             4843.51354135,
                             4642.51354135,
                             4465.51354135,
                             4910.51354135,
                             4846.51354135,
                             4204.51354135,
                             4240.51354135),
                   biomass = c(904.312546258,
                               666.312546258,
                               796.312546258,
                               792.312546258,
                               946.312546258,
                               768.312546258,
                               713.312546258,
                               715.312546258,
                               651.312546258,
                               772.312546258,
                               903.312546258,
                               920.312546258,
                               537.312546258,
                               550.312546258,
                               965.312546258,
                               633.312546258,
                               584.312546258,
                               909.312546258,
                               804.312546258,
                               840.312546258,
                               942.312546258,
                               925.312546258,
                               821.312546258,
                               613.312546258,
                               635.312546258,
                               917.312546258,
                               767.312546258,
                               944.312546258,
                               803.312546258,
                               521.312546258,
                               879.312546258,
                               653.312546258,
                               741.312546258,
                               798.312546258,
                               568.312546258,
                               785.312546258,
                               798.312546258,
                               672.312546258,
                               552.312546258,
                               637.312546258,
                               919.312546258,
                               522.312546258,
                               750.312546258,
                               640.312546258,
                               702.312546258,
                               634.312546258,
                               796.312546258,
                               897.312546258,
                               770.312546258,
                               870.312546258,
                               880.312546258,
                               696.312546258,
                               700.312546258,
                               850.312546258,
                               691.312546258,
                               802.312546258,
                               767.312546258),
                   plantCount1 = c(426,
                                   362,
                                   472,
                                   413,
                                   489,
                                   368,
                                   523,
                                   416,
                                   390,
                                   397,
                                   403,
                                   469,
                                   430,
                                   392,
                                   361,
                                   441,
                                   367,
                                   480,
                                   506,
                                   532,
                                   406,
                                   378,
                                   361,
                                   511,
                                   387,
                                   523,
                                   354,
                                   540,
                                   537,
                                   370,
                                   499,
                                   372,
                                   512,
                                   469,
                                   454,
                                   517,
                                   381,
                                   440,
                                   444,
                                   518,
                                   439,
                                   384,
                                   444,
                                   365,
                                   379,
                                   533,
                                   497,
                                   365,
                                   472,
                                   378,
                                   480,
                                   449,
                                   527,
                                   429,
                                   389,
                                   505,
                                   509),
                   plantCount2 = c(998,
                                   918,
                                   719,
                                   1018,
                                   791,
                                   1134,
                                   907,
                                   1184,
                                   972,
                                   1119,
                                   1142,
                                   965,
                                   769,
                                   1097,
                                   1120,
                                   1142,
                                   1047,
                                   900,
                                   970,
                                   945,
                                   791,
                                   1010,
                                   960,
                                   1017,
                                   914,
                                   985,
                                   998,
                                   688,
                                   925,
                                   784,
                                   927,
                                   980,
                                   1122,
                                   883,
                                   1053,
                                   1178,
                                   883,
                                   723,
                                   927,
                                   696,
                                   980,
                                   1067,
                                   727,
                                   671,
                                   681,
                                   980,
                                   1159,
                                   1138,
                                   1045,
                                   839,
                                   1154,
                                   1202,
                                   848,
                                   788,
                                   1012,
                                   1062,
                                   1093))
```

Comment: What are your units of measurement? In other words, where do the multiple measurements per treatment comes from?

Comment: @IsabellaGhement : Not sure what you're asking: Measurements were made for different levels of different factors.

Comment: I was just trying to understand what is being measured at each treatment level and whether you can assume independence of obsevations within that level. For example, you could measure yield for several sites within a treatment level, but if those sites are geographically close, their yield values may be related and that would have to be accounted for in your analysis.  But it seems like you've already accepted an answer to your question, so this is a mute point now.

Comment: Typically, in Agronomy experiments, an RCBD is an acceptable method for accounting for those geographically-close plots. Generally, you need to have 3 or more replications per treatment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start out with some data visualization.  With the help of R's package `ggplot2` I made

[image: four stripcharts of variable values versus treatment]

and there is no treatment effect to observe. For a formal analysis, I would just go for separate ANOVA's for each variable. You could also try MANOVA, but I do not see much point to it. For the record, here it is:

```
mod.manova <- manova(cbind(yield, biomass, plantCount1, plantCount2) ~ treatment, data=mydf)
summary(mod.manova)

          Df  Pillai approx F num Df den Df Pr(>F)
treatment  2 0.13504  0.94131      8    104 0.4861
Residuals 54
```

(I renamed your data frame `data` to `mydf`).  Anova could be replaced by some robust/rank-based alternative, as mentioned by the asker in comment, and there is also [robust alternatives to MANOVA](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/jasa.2011.tm09748).  Following is a version in R:

```
mod.rmanova <- rrcov::Wilks.test( treatment ~ yield + biomass + plantCount1 + plantCount2 , data=mydf)
mod.rmanova

    One-way MANOVA (Bartlett Chi2)

data:  x
Wilks' Lambda = 0.86776, Chi2-Value = 7.4468, DF = 8.0000, p-value =
0.4893
sample estimates:
     yield  biomass plantCount1 plantCount2
2 4450.461 764.9441    426.5789    995.3684
3 4533.829 769.8915    449.6316    935.0526
4 4634.514 741.1020    447.6842    951.0000
```

Here is the code for the plot:

```
mydf_long <- reshape2::melt(mydf)  
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydf_long, aes(value, treatment, color= treatment)) +
    geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ variable, scales="free_x")
```

Comment: Thanks! We had to use the Kruskal-Wallis test for our 1-way anova analysis, because in the real dataset, the data for each independent variable is not normally distributed (but they do have equal variances as according to the Bartlett test).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you could have a multifactorial experiment with several levels and use Anova to test for equality of treatments. :

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Multifactorial+Experiment+%2C+several+levels&t=ffnt&atb=v189-1&ia=web